# Increase Hibernate performance on big write/update

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I am trying to do a massive write/update to a database using hibernate taking data from an uploaded csv which can vary from 60,000 to 100,000 rows. I am using batch updates but even with that it takes quite some time i.e. 20+ min. Does anyone have any tips? I would like to avoid writing sql but is that the only way?

The current code

```
for (String row : rows) {
    String[] rowData = row.split(",");
    try {
        long userID = Long.parseLong(rowData[0]);
        int platformID = Integer.parseInt(rowData[1]);
        if (platformID == 14 && userID > 0) {
            MCTileScheduleEntity schedule = new MCTileScheduleEntity.Builder()
                                                .tile(tile)
                                                .userID(userID)
                                                .platformID(platformID)
                                                .startDate(startDate)
                                                .endDate(endDate)
                                                .build();
            if (existUser.add(userID)){
                schedules.add(schedule);    
            } else {
                error += 1;
                errMessage += "Duplicated data detected for user id "+ userID + "\n";
            }
        } else {
            error += 1;
            errMessage += "Malformed data detected for user id "+ userID + "\n";
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        error += 1;
        errMessage += "Non-numerical input for user id " + rowData[0] + "\n";
    }
}

if (error == 0) {
    //write to database in batches
    hb.batchUpdate(schedules);
    tile.setTargetCount(Long.valueOf(schedules.size()));
    hb.update(tile);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `hb.batchUpdate()` and `hb.update()`?

Comment: Clear the session cache after each commit. Disable the dirty checks (manual flush).

Comment: Thanks guys I won't be able to test it out your suggestion for a little bit but when I do I'll let you know how it goes